# How to make divs propperly expand and shrink?

Tags: html, css

My app is supposed to have a side menu, to navigate the different cattegories.
When the user clicks on one of the buttons in the side menu, the app is supposed to show the selected category, but I cant figure out how to display the selected category.
The area next to the side menu should also resize when I open the side menu
Here is the code I have so far:

```css
@import url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);


.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.menu-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.area-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}


.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:#212121;
/* border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5; */
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
  
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="main-container">
            <div class="menu-container">
                <nav class="main-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Dashboard
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-subnav">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Stars Components
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-subnav">
                            <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Forms
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-subnav">
                            <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Pages
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Graphs and Statistics
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                Quotes
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Tables
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Maps
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Documentation
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="logout">
                        <li>
                        <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
                                <span class="nav-text">
                                    Logout
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>  
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="area-container">
                <div class="area">
                    <p>Subscribe to Technoblade</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

  </body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </html>
```

I hope you can help me, and stay safe!

Comment: _css_ part, line 2, you have a extra `}`.
By the way you have to use more than CSS to do that.

Comment: To make sure I understand your question correctly, you want the `area-container` div to resize as the menu expands?

Comment: @need_to_know_now yes, that is what I want.

Comment: But that will ruin the UI, it will squish everything into a smaller area..

Comment: @need_to_know_now honestly im fine with both, as long as it works. I am planning to make the content of the different categories resizable anyways, but if it works it works and I am fine with it (._.)